# regexp match character before a specify string (not include)

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

REGEXP_SUBSTR(label) ,'.*_dis')

this is for sql;

my database is mysql

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(label) ,'.*_dis') as dis ,
substr(label,length(label))-1) as num
from table
```

table.lable col's  data:

```
1. a_b_dis_12
2. a_dis_13
3. c_d_dis_23
3. c_dis_22
```

i want to get  **the character before '_dis'**   and **the numeric part**   use regexp

```
1.a_b   12
2.a     13
3.c_d   23
4.c     22
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using.

Comment: You say, "get the character before '_dis'" but then show all the characters before '_dis'. Please clarify. If it's the latter just split on `'_dis_'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_substr` as follows:

```
Select regexp_substr(your_column, '^(.*)_dis_[0-9]+$',1,1,null,1) as dis,
       Regexp_substr(your_column, '[0-9]+$') as num
  From your table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(col, '^(.*)_dis.*$', '\1'),
       regexp_replace(col, '^.*_dis_([0-9]+)', '\1')
from (select 'a_b_dis_12' as col from dual union all
      select 'a_dis_13' as col from dual union all
      select 'c_d_dis_23' as col from dual union all
      select 'c_dis_22' as col from dual
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=340df14bceb6c5ddb887748a40cca1b0) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `regexp_replace()` as follows:

```
select
    regexp_replace(label, '_dis_.*$', '') dis,
    regexp_replace(label, '^.*_dis_', '') num
from mytable
```

The first expression suppresses everything from `'_dis_` (included) to the end of the string. The second expression removes everything from the beginning of the string until `'_dis_'` (included).